# ET.PenmanMonteith function in R: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : no rows to aggregate

Tags: r

I am using the ET.PenmanMonteith function ("Evapotranspiration" package, R). I have a list called data1 with Tmax, Tmin, RHmax, RHmin, Rs and u2, and also Date.daily(date) and Date.monthly(yearmon). Then, i have another list called constants, with all the constants required. I run the code but i get an error (*"Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : no rows to aggregate"*). My code is:

````
data=read_excel("prueba.xlsx")
head(data)

 Tmax  Tmin RHmax RHmin    u2    Rs
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  30.2  19.4  55.8 100     2.1  18.5
2  33.6  19.8  30.8  69.6   3.3  29.9
3  34.4  16    27.8  83.3   1.5  31.4
4  35.8  17    28.8  89.5   1.7  31.1
5  36.4  18    31.1  90.5   1.7  31.2
6  37.6  20.4  35.4  95.8   1.5  31.4

rnames=read_excel("prueba.xlsx",sheet="Hoja1")
head(rnames)
Tmax  Tmin RHmax RHmin    u2    Rs ...7  Date.daily Date.monthly
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <chr>      <chr>       
1  30.2  19.4  55.8 100      10  18.5 NA    1990-1-1   1990-1      
2  33.6  19.8  30.8  69.6    16  29.9 NA    1990-1-2   1990-1      
3  34.4  16    27.8  83.3     7  31.4 NA    1990-1-3   1990-1      
4  35.8  17    28.8  89.5     8  31.1 NA    1990-1-4   1990-1      
5  36.4  18    31.1  90.5     8  31.2 NA    1990-1-5   1990-1      
6  37.6  20.4  35.4  95.8     7  31.4 NA    1990-1-6   1990-1    

rnames=rnames[8]
colnames(rnames)="Date.daily"
rnames=as.Date(rnames$Date.daily)
rnames2=as.yearmon(rnames)
data1=cbind(rnames,rnames2,data)
as.Date(data1$rnames)
colnames(data1)=c("Data.daily","Data.monthly","Tmax","Tmin","RHmax","RHmin","u2","Rs")
data1=as.list(data1)
#List file is seen like this:[enter image description here][1]


#Constants data
constants=read_excel("constants.xlsx")
head(constants)

 lambda         sigma   Gsc   lat lat_rad as    bs     Elev     z
   <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   2.45 0.00000000490 0.082 -29.9  -0.521 NA    NA       88     2


constants=as.list(constants)
#List file is seen like this:[enter image description here][2]

res=ET.PenmanMonteith(data1, constants, ts="daily", solar="data",
                      wind="yes", crop="short", message="yes",
                      AdditionalStats="yes", save.csv="no")

Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate```


Could anyone help me?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJD78.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHNU7.png
````